# How to remove the space between words CSS

Tags: html, css

I added some **letter-spacing** to my strong elements and I had a large space at the beginning of each word : [image].

I tried to add **word-spacing: -4px** but space stays the same :/
How could I remove this space (between the "The" and the "852" ?) I would like each letter to be at the same distance. Like if there were no spaces between the words.

CSS:

```css
.sub-lead {
    text-align: justify;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

strong {
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}
```

HTML :

```html
<div class="sub-lead">
    <strong> THE </strong> 8 5 2 <strong> EXPERIENCE </strong> 9 0 <strong> YOU </strong> 0 8 5 <strong> ARE </strong>
</div>
```

PS: I also tried to remove the spaces in the code but it changes nothing.

EDIT: The space between each character of the text must be the same, even if it's not the same word. That's why I tried to use letter-spacing on strong elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is because you're adding multiple spaces together, but without `&nbsp;` in an inline text element, only one space will render. This is due to [white space collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space). This is causing the space to render at the first `letter-spacing`, which is big at the start, and smaller at the end. Adjust your spacing accordingly and it should work, e.g. *start* each section with a space, instead of adding one at the start and end.

Depending on the font rendering's actual size, you may still end up with some sub-pixel irregularity, but unless you want to remove all the spacing and add some `margin` to the `<strong>` tags, this is probably a decent starting point.

```css
.sub-lead {
    text-align: justify;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

strong {
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="sub-lead">
    <strong>THE</strong> 8 5 2<strong> EXPERIENCE</strong> 9 0<strong> YOU</strong> 0 8 5<strong> ARE</strong>
</div>
```

[image: Example rendering]

You could also make use of `white-space: pre-wrap;`. It *is* a semi-viable alternative, but whitespace is rendered both vertically and horizontally, so if you have *extra* spaces/breaks anywhere, you may end up with some funky results:

```css
.sub-lead {
    text-align: justify;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}

strong {
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="sub-lead">

    <strong>THE </strong> 8 5 2   <strong>   EXPERIENCE  </strong> 9 0  <strong> YOU   </strong> 0 8 5   <strong> ARE    </strong>
</div>
```

[image: Funky results]

Answer (score 0):

`word-spacing: 3px;` I believe not `letter-spacing: 3px;`

Comment: It works when I remove the **letter-spacing** but I need the letter in my strong words to be more spaced :/

Comment: Yeah, I tried but the space between each letter is not the same (between each character of the text, space should be the same even if it's not the same word).

Comment: ```<div class="sub-lead">
    <strong>THE</strong> 8 5 2 <strong> EXPERIENCE</strong>9 0 <strong> YOU</strong> 0 8 5 <strong> ARE </strong>
</div>```

try this maybe

Comment: imo you dont need to add the custom spaces because the more times you press the space bar, the more space will appear. You can do like 3 between bigger areas and 1 in normal spaced ares

Comment: I tried your code but the space between each character is not the same. The letter of the words in bold are closer than the space between the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some margin hiding in there. Consider using "span" instead of "strong" and make the text bold in your CSS. Span is great because it comes with 0 predefined styles, the same can't be said with almost any other html element.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't change anything. The thing is that when I don't use **letter-spacing**, it works but I really need the space between each letter of the text to be the same (even if it's not the same word). Here is the result without **letter-spacing** :https://imgur.com/a/zixwBKR

Answer (score 0):

Use a span tag instead, it allows you to select individual words(and letters if you really wanted to) without any other changes to the styles. It is a 100% customizable "container" and would definitely make this a lot easier.

Comment: That's what I'm doing at the moment, as @chris-neisen told me to do but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Bonsaï I would recommend clearing styles from the entire page using *{ } at the start just to make sure you have no lingering styles.